# Did King Solomon have any personal Prophets during his reign over Israel?

Tags: israel, prophets, solomon

We have record of King David having several prophets speak into his life who "kept him on the straight and narrow" or disciplined him when necessary. (Samuel, Nathan, Gad)

But I fail to find any prophets interacting with Solomon! Was this the reason for his ultimate apostasy? Did he make the mistake of relying on his gift of wisdom, without a continuing interaction with God?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nathan, who prophesied to David, was yet alive during Solomon's reign.

> And let Zadok the priest and Nathan the prophet anoint him there king
> over Israel: and blow ye with the trumpet, and say, God save king
> Solomon. (1 Kings 1:34, KJV)
>
> So Zadok the priest, and Nathan the prophet, and Benaiah the son of
> Jehoiada, and the Cherethites, and the Pelethites, went down, and
> caused Solomon to ride upon king David's mule, and brought him to
> Gihon. (1 Kings 1:38, KJV)
>
> Now the rest of the acts of Solomon, first and last, are they not
> written in the book of Nathan the prophet, and in the prophecy of
> Ahijah the Shilonite, and in the visions of Iddo the seer against
> Jeroboam the son of Nebat? (2 Chronicles 9:29, KJV)

Ahijah and Iddo prophesied to Jeroboam, who came after Solomon and was king for the ten tribes that split from Solomon's son Rehoboam. There is no record of them bringing a prophecy to Solomon.  Neither do we hear much about Nathan during Solomon's reign, apart from his assistance with and presence at Solomon's coronation.

Comment: @BiblasiaGood research. Are Wisdom and supernatural Prophetic words incompatible?  Or do humans  just become absorbed with their acumen such that they drift away slowly from the Source of their giftings? Would a few prophetic encounters  have changed the destiny of Israel--or even his sons outlook on life? Would a more aggressive approach by the Prophets been beneficial--instead of just taking notes and writing books? Jesus kept saying He could only do what He saw the Father doing, emphasizing the need for a continuous relationship (communication). Is there a message here?